# Where is Avengers HQ in the MCU?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

Over the course of Phase II and Phase III of the MCU, the Avengers renovate a former Stark Industries storage facility north of New York City and use it as their headquarters. From shots showing the Hudson River and Manhattan in the distance, I think it’s somewhere in Rockland County, perhaps near Nyack. Can anybody place it more precisely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this site](https://www.retrozap.com/mcu-location-scout-avengers-facility/)

> As you can see from the Google satellite view, the location above matches the original photographic background plate to a ‘T’. I can solidly proclaim that the Avengers are headquartered in **Esopus, New York!**

### [image]

> For Captain America: Civil War the layout was changed slightly and the entire facility was placed into context of the Hudson River Valley. According to Cinefex #147, an aerial plate was shot of an actual plot of land along the Hudson River. Effects artists then placed the buildings into that plate. When I first saw the image of the plate from that issue, I thought it would be impossible to find the actual location.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

The only thing we know about the location is that it is an "abandoned Stark Industries warehouse located in Upstate New York" however, it's kind of impossible to pin down a definitive location as it was filmed in London, Norwich and Atlanta.

Comment: I disagree. Panoramic shots featuring the headquarters fix it in a specific place. They don’t list an address but they do show a location.

Comment: @MichaelStern Are you asking where it is in-universe, or where it was filmed?

Comment: @GendoIkari in-universe

Comment: @MichaelStern Then I don't see how this answer is wrong. A panoramic shot showing the surrounding area would only give clues about where it was filmed; it wouldn't tell us anything about where it is meant to take place.

Comment: @GendoIkari somebody who knows the area well may be able to identify the location. The argument “the location can’t be known because it wasn’t actually filmed there” seems… confused. Scenes can have very specific locations even if filmed elsewhere or rendered in a computer.

Comment: @MichaelStern But it makes an unfounded assumption that the surrounding area was intentionally set up to recreate some location in upstate New York, instead of just being whatever surrounding area was naturally there in the place where it was filmed.

Comment: @GendoIkari we know it recreates a location in upstate New York because they show the Hudson River with Manhattan in the background. The question is only where along the Hudson River it is, and I’ll grab some screen caps later to make the point.